# SCORM Hosting Cross-Origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scorm, scorm1.2

I try to host a SCORM e-learning module decentralized on an other domain than my LMS (Learning Management System) is running. SCORM Modules are normally running in their own browser frame/window and communicating with the LMS directly, running all on the same domain. This is no problem because there is no security issue. Already tried this case with my code and it worked.

To archive the module is hosted on an other server I try to use something like a wrapper. These wrapper is hosted on the LMS, load the content from extern and communicates via postMessage with the LMS. I tried this open-source project: https://github.com/Didask/scol-r

But i don't get it work. Everytime i end up with the error: `Error grabbing 1.2 API-SecurityError:Blocked a frame with origin "https://..." from accessing a cross-origin frame. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`
So something try to access something that is not allowed. The exception is raised in the "SCORM_ScanParentsForApi" method.

I already ask the author of the project but he had no answer at all. I set up a small demo project in react to simulate an LMS. Added the wrapper module that point to my external content server where the SCORM module is hosted.

Maybe someone have an idea or can give my a hint.
I think it is something trivial. Hopefully ;)
Thanks!

Comment: what code are you using that you are seeing the resulting error from?

Comment: Test project is attached. Or use the link. If you click "Start module" a popup should occur that shows the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific problem is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSAllowOriginNotMatchingOrigin

So we are on sosafe.de and the skorm course is on lms0.sosafe.de
This will cause the CORS errors. You need your response headers to be accepted.

You can do this with your apache config. This will allow the response to get through.

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?:\/\/(.+\.)?sosafe\.de(:\d{1,5})?$" CORS=$0

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{CORS}e" env=CORS
Header merge  Vary "Origin"
```

You don't have to use this code exactly but, modify the server to add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. If you do `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` this would enable cross-origin requests from anywhere (though you should just allow domains you trust). This should solve your problem.

Else they should be on the same domain. which may not be possible due to the design of SCOL-R the scorm connector that allows you to reach the API.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html is already in use. With default config that will allow all origins. To do SCORM Cross Domain I use the above mentioned package, that will create something like a wrapper.

Comment: Somehow CORS is not enabled. Do a request and check.
`curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: https://sosafe.de" --head https://lms0.sosafe.de` This response doesn't include Access-Control-Allow-*. Thus I think you still have something to configure there.

Comment: I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin →* when I do a GET on https://lms0.sosafe.de/v1/content

Comment: perhaps it's just a same-origin policy issue. Maybe try changing your origin? `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin`

Comment: if I try to do something like > document.domain = "lms0.sosafe.de"; < I get "DOMException: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': 'lms0.sosafe.de' is not a suffix of 'sosafe.de'."

Comment: How about `document.domain = "sosafe.de";`

Comment: put it in both the iframe location and the parent location

Comment: does not change anything. try different variations. Cross-domain problem or different suffix error.

Comment: My last question prior to giving up. Does it work with a "." before sosafe.de `document.domain = ".sosafe.de"`

Comment: Did not work. Did you try to debug the test project? Would be a great step forward if we can find out what component is the problem. Content server, SCORM content, Wrapper or Player...

Comment: I did try the test project on scormcloud, did a debug. Same issue as you started with.

Comment: So LMS is not the problem. Content as well because its running in scormcloud without the wrapper. When the LMS is hosted on the content server using the wrapper loading the module from the same saver it is working. https://lms0.sosafe.de/v1/lms/ So content delivery is also work. The problem must be in the wrapper. I thinks its something with the postMessage system.

Comment: it's security issue we can't access other domain data, there are only two possibilities 1) host everything in single domain 2) enabling the cors on  the server

Comment: Did You solve your problem? I have same trouble. How can i set cors on c# server in this situation?